# Non-zero function $f(x)$ such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{t})}{t}dt-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{f(\frac{1}{t})}{t^2}dt=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Does there exists a function $f(x)\in L^2(0,1)$, not identically zero such that $$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{t})}{t}dt-\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{f(\frac{1}{t})}{t^2}dt=0$$

I am trying to construct a counterexample to certain problem which I have simplified to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variable $1/t=x$ transforms the equation into
$$
\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx.\tag{*}
$$
Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }0\le x<1/4\text{ or }1/2\le x\le1,\\
a & \text{if }1/4\le x\le1/3,\\
b & \text{if }1/3< x<1/2,
\end{cases}
\quad a,b\in\Bbb R.
$$
The equation ($*$) gives
$$
a\log\frac43+b\log\frac32=3\,a\log\frac43+2\,b\log\frac32.
$$
If
$$
2\,a\log\frac43+b\log\frac32=0,
$$
then $f$ verifies ($*$).

Comment: Thank you very much sir!!